# How to select non-immediate child elements?

Tags: html, css, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract an attribute's value from a few lines of HTML (of [this Reddit page](https://old.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/fwr4we/oc_cooccurrence_of_pokemon_types_visualised/)), do so for a few elements each, and then put those values in an array. (Basically to calculate the # of awards of a Reddit post.)

The code is not returning anything; awardCount is 0.

The goal: Check if there is a class called "awarding-link", and add up the # of different awards to get the total amount.

I have another issue: I need to check for that "awarding-link", but without the comment area. So they need to be child elements of the id "siteTable". The issue is I can't just use another ">" because that's for immediate child elements.

```
Sub GetData2()

Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim itemEle As Object, datacountobj As Object, awards As Object
Dim upvote As Integer

Dim postdate As String, upvotepercent As String, awardAdd As String, _
  awardCount As String, animated As String, dates As String, isanimated As String, _
  oc As String, filetype As String, linkurl As String, myhtmldata As String, _
  visiComments As String, totalComments As String, removedComments As String, _
  test As String, tested As String, test2 As String, test3 As String, title As String, _
  deletedComments As String

Dim y As Integer, x As Integer
Dim U As Long, L As Long, j As Long

Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate (ActiveCell.Value)
Do While IE.Busy = True Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

Dim nodeList As Object, i As Long, urls(), results(), results2()

    Set awards = IE.document.querySelectorAll("span.awardings-bar > awarding-link")
    If Not awards Is Nothing Then
        awardCount = 0
        For x = 0 To awards.Length - 1
            awardAdd = awards.getAttribute("data-count")
            awardCount = awardCount + awardAdd
        Next x
    Else
        awardCount = 0
    End If
    results(i + 1, 14) = awardCount
```

(results is just a 1D 0-based array)

Comment: In the link that you provided, I can't find any class with the `awarding-link` specific class that you provided. Are you sure this is the right element to select? Because `awardings-bar` is an empty `span`. Should I login to see the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You css selector is wrong so no results.

Switch to the shorter

```
.awarding-link
```

or use

```
span.awardings-bar > .awarding-link
```

Note the class selector `.` in front of awarding-link.

To avoid the comments being retrieved and limit just to awards section at top use a parent which restricts, for example:

```
.entry .awarding-link
```

Comment: Thanks @QHarr ! Oh, I forgot the dot. How did I not notice that. One last question: do you know how I can make sure it doesn't find elements that are in the comment section? 

As in, avoid elements that are child elements of the class "commentarea" ? Because sometimes comments get awards and then they have the exact same class and parent element, so they'd get counted in. I can't figure it out because "commentarea" isn't an immediate parent, it's a few levels up.

Comment: sorry to disturb you one last time (hopefully), but would you know why my awards.getAttribute("data-count") returns an error 438 - "Object doesn't support this property or method" ? awards is set like this.
`Set awards = IE.document.querySelectorAll("#siteTable .awarding-link")`

Can I do that? only defining feature that the comment area doesn't have is that id "siteTable".

Comment: Nevermind, I managed to get it right! Cheers, and thanks for all the help!